# accessing JS object with variable key

Tags: javascript, php

im passing an array with Laravel to my blade file and trying to access this with js inside.

This is my array from php:

```
$show_array = array (
  'jondoe_1' => '12.66',
  'jondoe_6' => '14.48',
  'jonsmith_23' => '22.10',
  'davejo_5' => '12.10',
);
```

Getting it is no problem.

```
    var array_ =  {!! json_encode($show_array) !!};
```

If I access anything like that its working :

```
    console.log(array_["jondoe_1"]);
```

But when I try to call it with a variable its not working

```
    string = array[i].name + "_" + array[i].number;
    console.log(array_[string ]);
```

Showing undefied.
Thanks in advance !

There is a simple solution I know...but trying for hours now and being stupid

Comment: Could you show us the content of array variable (not the array_) ?

Comment: Please `console.log(string)` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(array_))` and post their results here. Probably there's an additional space somewhere in `string`

Comment: Where is name & number coming from? Your string variable is probably not what you expect.

Comment: Does the assignment to `string` intentionally use `array` instead of `array_`?

Comment: @adiga console.log(string) = "jonsmith_23" | console.log(JSON.stringify(array_)) = {"jondoe_1":"12.66","jondoe_6":"14.48","jonsmith_23":"22.10","davejo_5":"12.10",}

Comment: @Bron `array` is an array of objects, `array_` is an object with string values. Yes, it's confusing to use similar variable names, but it seems clear that they should be different variables.